# P/B is isomorphic to the projective line $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Suppose that $P \subset G$ is a parabolic subgroup containing a Borel subgroup $B$. Moreover, let $P$ be a minimal parabolic subgroup properly containing B, i.e., one corresponding to a single root $\alpha$. Why is $P/B$ isomorphic to the projective line $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: I am confused. I thought Borel subgroups of an algebraic group *are* the minimal parabolics. [Wikipedia agrees with me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_subgroup). That would mean $P/B$ is trivial. Also, what do you mean by "containing a root"? A root is usually a character of a maximal torus in $B$, not an element of the group.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain I meant minimal non-trivial, i.e., a parabolic subgroup not containing any parabolic subgroup other than itself and the Borel, but not equal to the Borel. There is a theorem which says that parabolic subgroups are in bijection with subsets of the generators of the Weyl group (as a Coxeter group). So a minimal parabolic subgroup would be one corresponding to a single generator.

Comment: I think that the reason why this isomorphism holds is that we are really in an $SL(2)$ situation, since $P$ has a Levy decomposition where the Levi factor has semisimple rank 1. So $P/B \cong SL(2)/B'$, where $B'$ is the standard Borel in $SL(2)$, and $SL(2)/B'$ is isomorphic to the flag variety of 1-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^2$, i.e., the projective line. Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: Dear Balerion, What you call a *minimal* parabolic is usually called a *maximal* parabolic.  Regards,

Comment: Dear Balerion, Actually, I misunderstood; I think you mean a parabolic $P$ containing $B$, and such that there are no parabolics strictly between $B$ and $P$.  Is that right? Regards,

Comment: @MattE Yes, exactly.

Comment: Dear Balerion, Then I think that your explanation is correct.  Cheers,